# How to fix VBA regression code that works when executed without a button, but not with a button

Tags: excel, vba, button, regression

I'd like to tie my regression code to a button, but when I do, my regression code no longer works.

I have tried to be very explicit on where the ranges are, enabling more references (Solver, atpvbaen.xls, Ref Edit Control), and rewriting the syntax of my code.

```
Dim nextReg As Integer
Dim nextRegEnd As Integer
Dim regRowNum As Integer

Dim days As Integer
Dim cdd As Integer

nextReg = 1
nextRegEnd = 13
regRowNum = 20

days = 18
cdd = 20

Sheets("Reg_Work").Select

Do While Sheets("Reg_Work").Cells(regRowNum, 1).Value <> ""

    Sheets("Reg_Results").Activate
    'REGRESSION
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Sheets("Reg_Results").Range(Cells(nextReg, 1), Cells(nextRegEnd, 1)), Sheets("Reg_Work").Range("$I$4:$K$16"), False, True, , Sheets("Reg_Results").Cells(nextReg, 3), False, False, False, False, , False
    nextReg = nextReg + 21
    nextRegEnd = nextRegEnd + 21

Loop
```

I receive the error

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

when I expect it to perform the regression.

Comment: Avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` and specify in which sheet `Cells(nextReg, 1), Cells(nextRegEnd, 1)` are. This should fix your errors. You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). • Also declare your variables as `Long`, Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  PEH, if you look at the regression, code, you'll see I did specify in which sheet each cell reference is located.  Maybe I am misunderstanding what you offered.  Thank you for the comment about changing the declarations to Long, that helps :).  Mathieu Guindon, thank you for your response as well.  Not sure how I'd reference the range of values I need with the code change you offered however, again I may be misunderstanding what you wrote/just don't know.  I have tried it with and without application.run, and there was no change in the error message.Thanks again!

Comment: @lauren no in this code `Sheets("Reg_Results").Range(Cells(nextReg, 1), Cells(nextRegEnd, 1))` only your `Range` object has a sheet specified. But your two `Cells` objects have **no** sheet specified. It is acutally the same as if you write `Sheets("Reg_Results").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(nextReg, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(nextRegEnd, 1))`. Now if the active sheet is not `Reg_Results` it fails. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you specify a sheet for every `Range` and `Cells` object.

Note that in

```
Sheets("Reg_Results").Range(Cells(nextReg, 1), Cells(nextRegEnd, 1))
```

Only the `Range` object has a sheet specified but not the 2 `Cells` objects. It is the same as:

```
Sheets("Reg_Results").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(nextReg, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(nextRegEnd, 1))
```

But if `ActiveSheet` is not `Sheets("Reg_Results")` it fails. It should be

```
Sheets("Reg_Results").Range(Sheets("Reg_Results").Cells(nextReg, 1), Sheets("Reg_Results").Cells(nextRegEnd, 1))
```

Something like below should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub YourProcedure()
    Dim nextReg As Long
    nextReg = 1

    Dim nextRegEnd As Long
    nextRegEnd = 13

    Dim regRowNum As Long
    regRowNum = 20

    Dim days As Long
    days = 18

    Dim cdd As Long
    cdd = 20

    Dim wsWork As Worksheet
    Set wsWork = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reg_Work")

    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Set wsResults = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reg_Results")

    Do While wsWork.Cells(regRowNum, 1).Value <> vbNullString
        'REGRESSION
        Regress wsResults.Range(wsResults.Cells(nextReg, 1), wsResults.Cells(nextRegEnd, 1)), _
            wsWork.Range("$I$4:$K$16"), False, True, , _
            wsResults.Cells(nextReg, 3), False, False, False, False, , False
        nextReg = nextReg + 21
        nextRegEnd = nextRegEnd + 21
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: PEH thank you!  I understand now and that solved my problem.